Program runs indefinitely when I check hash map for repetition in rows/columns
I'm writing a Sudoku board generator. I thought of using a hash map to make sure that numbers are not repeated in the same row/column. The key is a string ("row"/"col" + number of row/col). After populating/checking a few rows, the program stops placing numbers and runs indefinitely. I'm not sure what I'm missing.
If I check my list.size() in my checkMap method (== 9), the program finishes alright, but some of the numbers are wrong.
class Board {
ArrayList<Integer> list;
Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
String key;
int value;
int[][] board = new int[9][9];

public Board() {
    for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < board.length; col++) {
            do {
                value = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 9 + 1); 
            } while (!checkValue(row, col, value));
                            //board[row][col] = value;
        }
    }
}

boolean checkValue(int row, int col, int value) {
    key = "row" + row;
    if (!checkMap(key, value)) {
        return false;
    }
    key = "col" + col;
    if (!checkMap(key, value)) {
        return false:
    }
    return true;
}

boolean checkMap(String key, int value) {
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    if (map.containsKey(key) {
        list = map.get(key);
        if (list.contains(value)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    list.add(value);
    map.put(key, list);
    return true;
}

}

Think about what happens to the list in your Map if a value is valid for the row, but not for the column.

Great observation, thank you!

A specific problem in your code is that in the checkValue method (applied to a specific cell and value) it first checks the row (calling checkMap), which then stores the value for that row if it is possible, and then it checks the column, and may discover that the cell was not possible. It then returns false, and the for loop will try again with a different value. But then it has already stored the first value as used in the row.
The bigger problem is that this way of generating a board won't work, unless you get extremely lucky in selecting the random numbers. Basically you need an algorithm for solving a sudoku board, and use that to check that your generated board has at least one solution (and ideally, you probably want it to have only one solution). For some pointers, have a look at the question How to generate Sudoku boards with unique solutions.

Thank you! You make very good points and I now realize that I was also using an algorithm for checking the validity of any given board as base -which falls apart when you start inserting numbers- instead of one for solving it.
